# Exception: "Could not gather sufficient random data"

Tags: php, symfony, mcrypt

A client gets the following error

> CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Could not gather
>   sufficient random data" at
>   /.../vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_mcrypt.php line
>   69 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Could not gather
>   sufficient random data at
>   /.../vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_mcrypt.php:69)"}
>   []

[Corrected client PHP version]

attempting to view or edit a record.  Client is on Symfony 2.8.2, PHP 5.6.18, running on freebsd.  My development system is Symfony 2.8.2, PHP 7, Windows 10 and does not get this error.

Running `composer update` did not affect this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer appears [here](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/91#issuecomment-191414036) courtesy of Scott at paragonie.  It says,

> It means precisely what it says: Something about your environment is
>   preventing mcrypt_create_iv($numBytesRequested, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
>   from generating enough entropy.
>
> Make sure PHP can read /dev/urandom, especially if you're in a chroot
>   jail. Without access to the kernel's CSPRNG, we cannot reliably
>   generate random data suitable for cryptography.

Since the site is on a shared host and I am largely freebsd illiterate, I forwarded this to the host's webmaster.  Issue solved.